# apache server hangs php-cgi, how can i debug further

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2012-r2, php5

We have Windows Server 2012 R2, Apache 2.2.31 and Php 5.6.18, Zend Server Version: 8.5.3

Apache seems to be hanging more and more frequently, a restart of apache seems to fix the problem most times. There are a quite a few php-cgi's open when we look at the the process viewer.

Windows event viewer shows multiple events like this,

```
18 JUL 2016 09:13:23
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.6.18.0, time stamp: 0x56b9d4d2
Faulting module name: php5.dll, version: 5.6.18.0, time stamp: 0x56b9d4ce
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002f8a02
Faulting process id: 0x1550
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1dfad0acd3f1b
Faulting application path: C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php5.dll
Report Id: e05b4091-4cc7-11e6-80bb-002590634814
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What things can i do to debug this further so I can figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A user reports a similar exception (0xc0000005) on stackoverflow which suggests that the problem is a memory access error, and the code accesses a nil pointer (or is blocked from access for protection reasons..);
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31535903/329931

Their remedy is to disable the EMET features on the binary exe. There is some information on disabling EMET features for specific applications here;
http://windowsitpro.com/security/using-emet-disable-specific-applications

If you are not running EMET, or that does not fix your problem, there is also a newer version 8.5.5 of Zend server which might include a bugfix;
http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads#Windows

and newer versions of php since 5.6.18 (current 5.6.22);
http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Comment: Thanks @Tom H, we don't run EMET on the server, but interesting read anyway. We are aware of the new version of zend server, and we have it running on our staging server at the moment, and will upgrade in due course. This server has been running 6 months now and has only started getting these issues in the last month or so, so i am not sure how likely it is related to the zend version.